# Using text box value as PHP variable

Tags: php

i am using a java script calender date picker in my php form,
it gives date in a text box. I want to use the text box value as a variable in php so that to use it in echo

for example:
my date picker is :-

```
echo "<input type=text id=exampleV name=dateIV maxlength=10 />";
```

the date picker is working fine

i want that date which comes in text box should be used as php variable

plz help

Comment: You need either `$_POST['dateIV']` or `$_GET['dateIV']` depending on what method you are using to submit the form.

Comment: But only mention: You cannot pass a JavaScript variable into the current page php code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the data (via a form) to a php file that handles that data. For example:

You can have a page with this code:

```
<form action="form.php" action="post">
<input type=text id=exampleV name=dateIV maxlength=10 />
<input type="submit">
```

And now you'll need `form.php` :

```
<?php
$variable = $_POST['dateIV'];
//Do some stuff here
echo $variable;
?>
```

I'm not sure why you're `echo`ing that HTML input element; that can be created statically in an HTML file. However, if your intent is to dynamically generate HTML/JavaScript and expect your users' inputs to interact with other PHP on the same page, that won't work. Remember PHP is all server-side, and it generates text/data that's displayed client side (where JavaScript runs). No logic in PHP will work post file execution. So you'll need to use forms and submit the data to another PHP file.

Comment: I agree with you,, your answer is valid, but just to make things more valid I felt like I need to say that you can post any form onto itself, it does not have to be necessarily a different php file.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen I agree with what you are saying, however, this gets a little bit more complicated since you will have to set a flag of some sort. What I mean by that: if you post a form to itself (same file), presumably in one "mode" it will display the form and in another "mode" it must process the form instead of displaying it. But that all depends on what the function of this thing is.

Answer (score 0):

You can only store it in a PHP variable by doing a POST or a GET.
If you want this to happen asynchronously, use `AJAX`.

Call an AJAX POST whenever the value of the `dateIV` is set with the `datepicker`.

Typically, it should be inside the `onselect` function of the datepicker

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of to put as a PHP Variable Can you give more details and Specific.

Or you can use data from Text-field by using

> `jQuery("Textfield_ID").val()`